# Disable redirect to https - Nginx

Tags: nginx

My current configuration for `Nginx` is

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.html;

    server_name url.tdl;


   location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:2368;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name url.tdl; # Replace with your domain

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /root/url.tdl.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /url.tdl.me.key;

    client_max_body_size 10G;

        location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:2368;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_buffering off;
    } 
}
```

In the above configuration file, I have no redirects written, but still the website redirects to HTTPS.

According to [nginx - Disable http to https redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30072777/nginx-disable-http-to-https-redirect), they have disabled `listen 443` but I want to have the `443` as an option.

Is there any way to keep both options?