# Disable HTTP->HTTPS redirect and leave my site HTTP only with Nginx?

Tags: nginx

I am a Nginx newb stuck on something that doesn't have a tutorial available for it. I got myself into this mess following DigitalOcean Nginx tutorials, but I can't remember which ones I did to get here in which order, so I can't reverse engineer a solution.

My goal is to take my site, currently https://coderjobmarket.com, and use only HTTP. I want to do this because the Flask server serving data from my backend is also in HTTP, and it's simply less of a headache to make my entire site HTTP instead of trying to get a SSL certificate for my Flask server.

But I am new, guys, so new. I don't even know what information to post here, really, so please let me know if I'm leaving out anything important.

I looked at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30072777/nginx-disable-http-to-https-redirect) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893839/how-do-i-redirect-https-to-http-on-nginx) but the answers are way over my head.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 (also new to Ubuntu; I'm a windows user) and Nginx 1.14.0.

So far I have the file at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/coderjobmarket.com` open using `sudo nano`. I understand this file is my "server block". It reads like this:

```
server {

        root /var/www/coderjobmarket.com/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name coderjobmarket.com www.coderjobmarket.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/coderjobmarket.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/coderjobmarket.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = coderjobmarket.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name coderjobmarket.com www.coderjobmarket.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

I tried (1) changing the file to reflect "listen on port 80" in the first `server{}` block, (2) commenting out the `ssl_certificate` lines & `include [...]` + `ssl_dhparam [...]` and (3) changing `return 301 https://$host$request_uri;` to `return 200 http://$host$request_uri;` but that resulted in the following error messages when I did `sudo nginx -t`:

```
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "coderjobmarket.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.coderjobmarket.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "coderjobmarket.com" on [::]:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.coderjobmarket.com" on [::]:80, ignored
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

*please tell me what other info I should be posting or looking at to make this a successful post, I really don't know*

Comment: do you have another file on `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` ? that may have kind of same server_name ?

Comment: @Jean-JacquesMOIROUX I ended up reinstalling Nginx from scratch! Thanks for your comment